# Different Output in StreamWrite and Debug.log

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging, io, outputstream

for my current project I'm using Unity to make a simulation and log some data. It is basically just a car and I'm trying to log these things:

1. nodes = My Waypoints
2. Time out = my Output Time, this is the current time for this lap
3. Speed = the speed of the car at this moment
4. xPos = the x Position
5. zPos = the z Position

This logging script is working fine for my data.txt and I get this result.

```
1 1 0.2876698 -3.296932 95.41293
1 2.02 1.095865 -3.286392 94.23542
1 3.04 2.818792 -3.264626 92.27694
1 4.08 3.079535 -3.226411 89.4863
1 5.12 2.492892 -3.171062 85.86295
```

Now I wanted to add a second script which is giving me the time I need for each lap, in order to check if we have a constant time for this. And I would have to have it in this manner: lap number time.

If I want to print this out I'm getting this result results:

```
lap time
62.02
```

So I was suprised since it is the same time variable as in my first data logger, so I wanted to check out what was wrong and put the same command from my first logger into the Debug.log and I got the same result as my 2nd Logger.

[Debug Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq8BM.png)

So now I'm just wondering how the exact same line can give me two different Outputs and how I would get my lap timer working the way he is supposed to work.

This is the complete code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class SaveToFile : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Auto;

private CarEngine Engine;

public float speed;
public float maxSpeed;
public float time;
public float motorTorque;
public float breakTorque;
public float steerAngle;
public float node;
public bool IsRunning = true;
public int WaitTimer = 1;
public float xPos;
public float zPos;
public bool cancel = false;
public bool lap = false;
public float time_out;
public float time_lap;
public int lapNum;


void Start()
{
    Engine = Auto.GetComponent<CarEngine>();

    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\kaykl\Documents\Schule\Info\Data\CarControle\lap.txt");
    writer.WriteLine("lap time");
    writer.Close();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    motorTorque = Engine.maxMotorTorque;
    breakTorque = Engine.maxBrakeTorque;
    steerAngle = Engine.maxSteerAngle;
    maxSpeed = Engine.maxSpeed;
    speed = Engine.currentSpeed;
    time = Time.time;
    node = Engine.node;
    xPos = Auto.transform.position.x;
    zPos = Auto.transform.position.z;
    lap = Engine.lap;
    time_out = time - time_lap;

    if(lap == true && time_out > 5)
    {
        time_lap = Time.time;
        lapNum = lapNum + 1;
        StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\kaykl\Documents\Schule\Info\Data\CarControle\lap.txt");
        writer.WriteLine(lapNum +'+'+time_out);
        writer.Close();

    }

    if (IsRunning == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
    }


}

public IEnumerator Wait()
{
    IsRunning = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTimer);
    Output();
    IsRunning = true;
}

void Output()
{
    Debug.Log(node + " " + time_out + " " + speed + " " + xPos + " " + zPos);
    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\kaykl\Documents\Schule\Info\Data\CarControle\data.txt");
    writer.WriteLine(node + " " + time_out + " " + speed + " " + xPos + " " + zPos);
    writer.Close();

}
```

}

I just want to say thank you for each of you in advance, it probably is a stupid error of mine but I'm just not getting it right now.

// EDIT

Ok so now this is my working code. I used the writer.flush() and then my Debug.log was correct but my lap.txt was still wrong.
After I changed my WriteLine inside Start() into output() it somehow worked. So this is my now working code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class SaveToFile : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Auto;

private CarEngine Engine;

public float speed;
public float maxSpeed;
public float time;
public float motorTorque;
public float breakTorque;
public float steerAngle;
public float node;
public bool IsRunning = true;
public int WaitTimer = 1;
public float xPos;
public float zPos;
public bool cancel = false;
public bool lap = false;
public float time_out;
public float time_lap;
public int lapNum;


void Start()
{
    Engine = Auto.GetComponent<CarEngine>();

    Output();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    motorTorque = Engine.maxMotorTorque;
    breakTorque = Engine.maxBrakeTorque;
    steerAngle = Engine.maxSteerAngle;
    maxSpeed = Engine.maxSpeed;
    speed = Engine.currentSpeed;
    time = Time.time;
    node = Engine.node;
    xPos = Auto.transform.position.x;
    zPos = Auto.transform.position.z;
    lap = Engine.lap;
    time_out = time - time_lap;

    if(lap == true && time_out > 5)
    {
        time_lap = Time.time;
        lapNum = lapNum + 1;
        StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\kaykl\Documents\Schule\Info\Data\CarControle\lap.txt");
        writer.WriteLine(time_out);
        writer.Flush();

        writer.Close();

    }

    if (IsRunning == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
    }


}

public IEnumerator Wait()
{
    IsRunning = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTimer);
    Output();
    IsRunning = true;
}

void Output()
{
    Debug.Log(node + " " + time_out + " " + speed + " " + xPos + " " + zPos);
    StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\kaykl\Documents\Schule\Info\Data\CarControle\data.txt");
    writer.WriteLine(node + " " + time_out + " " + speed + " " + xPos + " " + zPos);
    writer.Flush();

    writer.Close();

}
```

}

Can anyone explain to me how just refering to the method instead of writing it down fixed the problem?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Try writer.Flush() before the Close() method.

Comment: First thank you, now it is working in the Console, but I still get wrong values in my lap.txt I copied my other WriteLine command in there to see if it would print this out, but it still prints the same Output as in my original post. So there has to be something else.

Comment: Ok fixed it somehow, even tough I'm not quite sure how ;) Working Code is added to question

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. I added the writer.Flush() which made it better, but still I got some weird data out of it. The problem was, that when I wanted to print out the current lap and the time I used this line:

```
writer.WriteLine(lapNum+' '+time_out);
```

I completely forgot, that I'm not working in Python anymore so I used 'x' to declare a string instead of "x". I changed it to

```
writer.WriteLine(lapNum+" "+time_out);
```

And now it is working.
Thanks for the help :)